# How do I debug this Strapi error about record creation?

Tags: strapi

One content type is refusing to create records returning the error "an error occurred during content creation". Other content types seem unaffected. There are currently 2 items that have already been created for this content type so it was working previously.

I'm trying to figure out where to look for error logs, the Node console returns no errors and there are no Mysql database errors in the mysql log file.

Freebsd 12.0-RELEASE-p10
Mysql 8.0.17
Strapi 3.0.0-alpha.26.2

Comment: Can you me more context about what you did exactly

Comment: The problem turned out to be caused by a server limit on max file size. It would be good if Strapi could give some more details in its error messages to help debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be caused by a server limit on max file size but Strapi was only returning a generic error message.